# Ruby on rails how to get Delayed::job Handler content as String

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

i have model contact_message. Every time i send one i create a timeout delayed job like that:

> Delayed::Job.enqueue ContactMessageTimout.new(self.permalink) ..

I would really like the possibility to get back the permalink in a delayed::job so i could know which contact_message has a delayed_job
BUT the information is encoded in the key 'handler' like this:

```
--- !ruby/struct:ContactMessageTimeout
message_permalink: !binary |-
  ZmY2YzAxOTM0MDRjNmIzMjQzMzg=
```

And the real permalink is : ff6c0193404c6b324338

So how can i deserialize the content of the delayed::job handler?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be Base64 encoding, which converts binary into a format that is safe for XML.  You can verify this in the rails console:

```
 my_proj » Base64.decode64("ZmY2YzAxOTM0MDRjNmIzMjQzMzg=")
 => "ff6c0193404c6b324338"
```

And of course, you can simply make the same call in your code to get your binary value back.

Comment: That worked! But after more examination i see that sometimes they are encoded and sometimes not. Do you know why?

Comment: I'm guessing that if there are non-printable characters, it will do the encoding automatically.  Another alternative would be to convert the binary value to a string (in hex) before you save it.  Then convert it back yourself on the DJ side.